# How to merge 2 custom post type permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have 2 post types.

- Course
- Lesson

All lessons belong to the `Course` post type. Each `lesson` store the course ID in its meta.

I have a question for the permalink structure.

For the Course, I want below the permalink structure.

```
example.com/course/{course-category}/{course-title}
```

And for Lesson:

```
example.com/course/{course-category}/{course-title}/{lesson-title}
```

Or

```
example.com/course/{course-category}/{course-title}/lesson/{lesson-title}
```

E.g.

For **Course**:

If I have a course title 'First Course' in the category 'Cat 1'.

Then the expected URL is:

```
example.com/course/cat-1/first-course
```

---

For **Lesson**:

If I have a "Lesson" is 'Getting Started' and its Course is to 'First Course'.

Then the expected URL is:

```
example.com/course/cat-1/first-course/getting-started
```

or

```
example.com/course/cat-1/first-course/lesson/getting-started
```

---

Is this possible?

I have tried and make a course URL in work.

Currently **working** Course URL like:

```
example.com/course/cat-1/first-course
```

Lesson URL is also working as below:

```
example.com/course/first-course/lesson/getting-started
```

But, expected the 'cat-1' like:

```
example.com/course/cat-1/first-course/lesson/getting-started
```

Comment: Are you referring to the standard Post category? Do you use a plugin to register the post types ("course" and "lesson")? If not, can you add your code (which calls `register_post_type()`)? And what is the meta key?

Comment: Im not referring to the standard Post category. I'm using plugin to register the post types ("course" and "lesson"). And the meta key is my-course-id which store the course id into the lesson post.

Comment: Ok, but have you attempted any custom code? Are the post types hierarchical? Is the custom taxonomy hierarchical? And what plugin you use?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have the Lessons post_type part of the Course post_type at all. IMHO Course should be a custom taxonomy of Lesson post type.